# Starting a virtual device in Visual Studio 2015 error (haxm not installed)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I would like to run this (Visual Studio 2015):
[image: e1]

But it throws this error:
[image: e2]

I tried to install HAXM, but I couldn't:
[image: e3]

My processor:
[image: e4]

What could be the problem?

Comment: I am not familiar with this at all, but here's something to check: Are the required hardware virtualization features enabled in your BIOS? Some consumer-grade machines ship with them disabled.

Comment: I enabled in BIOS the "Intel Virtualization Technology". It was disabled by default. I tried enabling/disabling Hyper-V options in "Windows Features activate or deactivate". Nothing helped. I still can't install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer).

Answer (score 0):

I enabled "Intel Virtualization Technology" in the BIOS,
deactivated the Hyper-V options in "Windows Features activate or deactivate",
manually downloaded Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM),
uninstalled Android N (API 24) and Android N (API 25) and removed API24 and API25 build tools, renamed folder "22.0.2" to "25.0.2" in ..\Android\android-sdk\build-tools.
And it worked.